# Adding a SSL App engine with custom subdomain pointing to Google Storage bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine-python

Current App:

- Goole App Engine on a custom domain: `myapp.com`
- Google Cloud Storage bucket on a custom subdomain (it uses DNS): `images.myapp.com`
- I have SSL certificate with the `images` subdomain

My question is: Is possible to have this configuration with SSL?

Things I have tried:

- *Load balancer*. I cannot figure out how to redirect everything that is not `/images/*` to the GAE (it seems it only works with backends)
- *`dispatch.yaml`*. I think it only works for the services you deploy
- In *App Engine Settings* I have added `images.myapp.com`, but as the redirection of `images.myapp.com` is done at DNS level, the secure layer is lost

Any suggestion or idea is more than welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation comes from the Cloud Storage bucket presented as a website under a custom domain - you can't use SSL with that. From [You want your content served through HTTPS](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https):

> SSL is not currently supported by the Cloud Storage webservers; thus,
>   you can only use a CNAME redirect with HTTP and not with HTTPS. If you
>   wish to serve content through HTTPS from your bucket, we recommend you
>   use a [third-party Content Delivery Network](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/09/push-google-cloud-origin-content-out-to-users.html) with Cloud Storage.
>   Alternatively, you can serve your static website content from
>   [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) instead of Google Cloud Storage.

If the content of your site meets the [Code and static data storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Code) quota you can serve your website through GAE, as static content (through a google CDN), which can be mapped to a custom domain and use SSL. See:

- [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files)
- [Hosting a static website on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website)

If your content exceeds the mentioned quota then you can still serve it through your app, but dynamically, with your app accessing the content stored on GCS and serving it - more expensive as you'll be using instance hours for it.